# Terminal widget in GTK application

Tags: python, linux, terminal, gtk, vte

I need something like terminal widget in my app, but without shell like a Bash. I've heared about VTE. To connect VTE with shell I've used:

```
Vte.Terminal.fork_command_full(0, "/home/user", ("/bin/bash",), "", 0, None, None)
```

Is any possibility to redirect input data to custom function instead of shell?

If it is impossible with VTE I'm isteresting for other propostitions how solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried substituting another command there instead of /bin/bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any command you want to `fork_command_full`, but, it almost sounds like you want something more like a text entry where you allow the user to enter a command, and then your code handles both executing the command and processing the data it returns.

For that I would use `subprocess.Popen` and then load the output of the command into a `Gtk.TextView` using text tags to mark stderr as red text.

Comment: Yes, but I want make something like a SSH/Telnet/Serial terminal. Does Gtk.TextView to do so good?